# Removing selected geojson feature with Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API to let users draw custom polygons with properties to be entered into a database. Before inserting them into the database though, they need to be able to delete selected shapes they've drawn.

This function isn't throwing any errors but it also isn't deleting the feature. What am I doing wrong?

```
var selectedshape;

function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
     zoom: 1,
     center: { lat: -1, lng: 1 }
 });

 function clearSelection() {
     if (selectedShape) {
         selectedShape = null;
     }
 }

 function setSelection(shape) {
     clearSelection();
     selectedShape = shape;
 }

 map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
     map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].clear()
     setSelection(event.feature);
         map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(centerControlDiv);
     map.data.revertStyle();
     map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, { strokeWeight: 8 });
     selectID = event.feature.getProperty('uniqid')
     selectID = event.feature.getProperty('uniqgeom')
     $(".getSelectID").attr("id", selectID)
 });

 bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(event) {
      processPoints(event.feature.getGeometry(), bounds.extend, bounds);

      map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
      map.fitBounds(bounds);

     var uniqid = "_" + Date.now();

     feature_type = event.feature.getGeometry().getType()

     if (feature_type == 'LineString') {
         encoded_geom = event.feature.getProperty('uniqgeom') || google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(event.feature.getGeometry().getArray());
     } else {
         encoded_geom = event.feature.getProperty('uniqgeom') || google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(event.feature.getGeometry().getArray()[0].getArray())
     }
     event.feature.setProperty('encoded_geom', encoded_geom);
     selectID = encoded_geom
     $(".getSelectID").attr("id", selectID)
     event.feature.setProperty('uniqid', uniqid);
 });


function deleteSelectedShape() {
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].clear()
 if (selectedShape) {

     map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
         if (feature.getProperty('uniqid') == selectedShape.uniqid) {
             map.data.remove(feature);
         }
     });
 }
}
```

I believe the problem is a syntax error in

```
 if (feature.getProperty('uniqid') == selectedShape.uniqid) {
```

Comment: `if (feature.getProperty('uniqid') == selectedShape.getProperty('uniqid'))`

Comment: That worked! I knew it was a dumb syntax issue, thanks!

Comment: But I don't think that you need the loop, `if(selectedShape){map.data.remove(selectedShape);clearSelection();}` should be sufficient